# Is there any similar function of R's 'duplicated' in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

duplicated() determines which elements of a vector or data frame are duplicates of elements with smaller subscripts, and returns a logical vector indicating which elements (rows) are duplicates.

Is there any similar function in MATLAB to do the same operation?

Comment: Have you looked at `duplicated` function?

Comment: Check _unique_, this does what you said.

Answer (score 0):

```
vec = [1 2 3 4 5 6 1 2 3 7 8 9]; % example data
[~,ind,~] = unique(vec); % finding unique indices
duplicate_indices = setdiff(1:numel(vec), ind); % deducing duplicates
```